# Google App Script not working in incognito mode

Tags: google-apps-script

i've been learning with google app script, and tried to make a web form because of the limitation of google form. I tried making it by following this [example](https://bionicteaching.com/custom-web-form-to-google-sheets/), and it works. However when I tried using incognito or other browser without a google account log on to it, it failed, showing this error

> "Maaf, terjadi error pada server saat membaca dari penyimpanan. Kode error INTERNAL."

Which is in Indonesian that basically states the server failed to read the file, and there is an internal error. [This](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyEMo9FgC4u3_Jv67b6MrhoRPfbkdzpBqrWvP5F-h73/dev) is the web app script.

[Settings for the web app deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHYxd.jpg)

Also in the spreadsheet linked is set to anyone with link is able to edit. When this is changed to anyone with link is able to view only, causes a log in prompt to appear in incognito mode.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I also found out earlier that this problem occurred previously because of a bug by google, but it has been resolved. So did I do something wrong?

Comment: Hello @Ario, are you still getting the error? I tried accessing the link you posted but I am able to view the form successfully.

Comment: Alright guys I have realized my mistake. It was because I was using the dev link for the web app (testing purpose) and not the current live version URL.

After using the current live URL it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Apps Script Web Apps documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app):

> The first is labeled Current web app URL and ends in /exec. **This URL is for the published version of your app, based on the last version you saved and deployed**.

> The second is the link labeled latest code and ends in /dev. This URL can only be accessed by users who have edit access to the script. This instance of the app always runs the most recently saved code — not necessarily a formal version — and is intended for quick testing during development.

Therefore, when sharing the web application, you should be sharing the **/exec** link.

Comment: Yes I have realised that this is the problem. I made a mistake in using the wrong URL. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There is an open bug for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160665120

Comment: Yes thanks, I also have been looking through that issue, and it seems it was a mistake that I made. I used the dev link and not the current web app link. So all is good now.